# SHA - Output of program is different from sha512sum command

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha512

In summary, I program for first time with **openssl/sha.h** and everything goes right in compilation. here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>


int main()
{
    int j;

    FILE *hash_file = fopen("hash.txt", "wb");

    for(j = 0; j < 256; j++)
    {
        unsigned char md[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        char* fileName = malloc(sizeof(int));
        sprintf(fileName, "%X%s", j, ".txt");

        int i;
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
        SHA512_CTX mdcontext;

        int bytes;
        unsigned char data[2048];

        if(file == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s can not be opened\n", fileName);
            return;
        }

        SHA512_Init(&mdcontext);

        while((bytes = fread(data, 1, 2048, file) != 0))
            SHA512_Update(&mdcontext, data, bytes);

        SHA512_Final(md, &mdcontext);

        for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            printf("%x", md[i]);
            fprintf(hash_file, "%x", md[i]);
        }
        // fprintf(hash_file, "\n");
        printf("\n");
        free(fileName);
        fclose(file);
    }

    fclose(hash_file);
    return 0;
}
```

and I have this output :

```
711c22448e721e5491d8245b49425aa861f1fc4a15287f735e23799b65cffec5b5abdfddd91cd643aeb3b530d48f5e258e7e230a94ed525c1387bb4e1b
```

But when I hash same file with **sha512sum** command in Linux i got this output:

```
6e3ea4bec3cd738f06f011c2f4ee4f6cd6d12205cafe41c083d52f94d9de4ab8b9e702664a367b633be14024a96e88a140a2e7fee4dc2c6e2f0bd436e281e35b  make.sh
```

what is the problem?

Comment: it seems that you are doing the hashes of two different files. The c code opens `hash.txt` and you passed to `sha512sum` command the file `make.sh`. If they have different contents, of course you'll get different hashes.

Comment: `char *fileName = malloc(sizeof(int));` is broken; either use `sizeof(int) * 3 + sizeof ".txt"` or `asprintf()`.

Comment: @ensc `asprintf` is a GNU extension, if the code has to be portable, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Not your whole problem, but `printf("%x", md[i])` is wrong.  It will strip leading zeroes.  (I notice that your output is only 488 bits long.)  Use `printf("%02x", md[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh boi!

A tiny little parantheses can make you pull your hair out.

The problem is in this statement `while((bytes = fread(data, 1, 2048, file) != 0))`. You see, in this statement the `!=` condition will be evaluated first. So, when `fread` reads (and returns), let's say `n` number of characters, it checks if `n!=0`. If it evaluates to `true` then it sets `bytes` to `1` (`true` is casted to `1`).

And now, the function `SHA512_Update(&mdcontext, data, bytes);` becomes `SHA512_Update(&mdcontext, data, 1);` while it should have been `SHA512_Update(&mdcontext, data, n);` (where `n` is the number of characters successfully read).

#### Solution

Change `while((bytes = fread(data, 1, 2048, file) != 0))` to `while((bytes = fread(data, 1, 2048, file)) != 0)`.

#### Update [Saving the hash in a `char` array]:

The output of `SHA512` is of 128 characters. So, we need a `char` array of size twice that of `SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH` (64). Then, we can just store it in the `char` array using `sprintf`.

```
char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    sprintf(&hash[i*2], "%02x", md[i]);
```

Why `i*2`? Because output has a width of 2 bytes. So, result will be stored at `hash[i]` and `hash[i+1]`.

Now, to print it:

```
for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH*2; i++)
    printf("%c", hash[i]);
```

**PS**: 
Read about [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

And don't forget to follow the advices in comments to your post, especially the one about using `%02x` by Steve.

Comment: it works well now! :D thank you and sorry for my stupid mistake!

Comment: may i ask how can i save the hash in array?

Comment: @Iman. I've updated the answer. Also, you might want to add this question to your original post.

Comment: nice answer! it's a perfect answer vishal. thank you